problems linking devices on whatsapp
I have a few phones and a laptop.
I also have whatsapp on my laptop.
One of my phones call it PhoneA- had whatsapp on it and a sim card in there. It happens to be a bit slow. It still has whataspp on it and is still a bit slow and I still have it but it no longer has a SIM card in there.
Another phone, phone B happens to be faster than phoneA, maybe less annoying in some ways, and I switched the Sim card from PhoneA, to PhoneB. And left PhoneB in my car, and Phone B, got stolen from my car.
So now I have PhoneA which is slow and has whatsapp on it. And I have my laptop with whatsapp on it.
I have bought a new  fast phone, PhoneC
So to recap, PhoneA is my slow one. PhoneC is my new fast one.  PhoneB was stolen.  Also PhoneC has a new SIM card in there. (my old SIM card was in PhoneB and so got stolen with it).
I want to transfer whatsapp from my slow phone(PhoneA), or my laptop, to Phone C
I understand that only one phone can have whatsapp at a time, and various non-devices can have it simultaneously
If I try to get the QR code showing on PhoneA, so I go to PhoneA (the slow phone with whatsapp on it), and I choose settings, and then choose that grid picture, then it shows a QR code. So I get that.
If I go to PhoneC (the fast phone where I want to trnsfer whatsapp to it from PhoneA),  and I try to scan the QR code, then  PhoneC says "Invalid QR Code"  "Make sure you're scanning a QR code displayed on WhatsApp Web, Desktop, Portal, or any other official WhatsApp app. If it continues to not work, update the app or refresh the page and try again".
If I try to get the QR code showing on my laptop's whatsapp, then it seems I can do that by opening an incognito window and going to web.whatsapp.com  So i do that. It shows a QR Code. So I get that.
If I then go to Phone C(the fast phone where I want to transfer whatsapp to it from my laptop), then I go to linked devices and scan the QR code. then the Whatsapp in the incognito window gets the Whatsapp from PhoneC. That makes me think oh darn I hope I haven't lost all the whatsapp info from my desktop. But fortunately when I chose that window it's fine.
I on Phone A(my slow phone with whatsapp showing with my messages), I go to Chats..chat backup and it lists a google account call it blahiam@gmail.com
If I go onto PhoneC(my fast phone with blank whatsapp), and I go to Chats..chat backup, then it lists that same google account  blahiam@gmail.com. But it says "Backup your chats and media", Local: Never.  Last Backup: Never. And it has a backup button. (no point me clicking it though as it's a blank whatsapp. And I certainly don't want it overwriting the backup from PhoneA.
Also when I started Whatsapp on PhoneC, it did ask me for an email account for added security, and I said no. I've not had to pick that email account option before.
I suppose one thing I haven't done is generate a QR code on the whatsapp on my fast phone, try to scan it from the Whatsapp on my slow phone that has the Whatsapp. But i'm wary of wiping the Whatsapp on my slow phone.   I'm not really sure what direction whatsapp is meant to transfer either when scaning a QR code..
I'm not sure how to go about this.  Getting Whatsapp with messages on my new phone.
And I don't know if the fact that PhoneB got stolen and had my SIM card in it, the SIM card that was maybe in PhoneA, is an issue.

AFAIK, you need to back up the database backup locally (just in case), then change the phone number before transferring the data to the new phone.

@AndrewT. thanks, any idea re https://superuser.com/questions/1846084/how-do-i-load-a-local-whatsapp-backup-on-my-desktop-without-interfering-with-wh  ?
